# update k8s in minikube

Tags: linux, kubernetes, upgrade, minikube

Im running:

```
:~$ minikube version

minikube version: v1.20.0

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.6", GitCommit:"8a62859e515889f07e3e3be6a1080413f17cf2c3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-15T03:28:42Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.6", GitCommit:"fbf646b339dc52336b55d8ec85c181981b86331a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-18T12:01:36Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Is it possible to upgrade ONLY kubernetes in minikube installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start `minikube` with a `k8s` version of your choice

```
▶ minikube start --kubernetes-version=1.22.1
  minikube v1.23.0 on Darwin 11.6.1
✨  Using the virtualbox driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  minikube 1.25.1 is available! Download it: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.25.1
  To disable this notice, run: 'minikube config set WantUpdateNotification false'
```

Comment: make sure to choose a kubernetes version that is supported by minikube: choose one from the output of `minikube config defaults kubernetes-version`

I broke a minikube cluster by randomly choosing an unsupported version.. You can also use `--kubernetes-version=latest` if you want the newest, which saves a bit of time

Comment: Also, you need to stop the cluster before doing this: `minikube stop`, or you'll get port collisions.

This solution will permanently upgrade the selected minikube profile (the default, "minikube", in this case) to the new kubernetes version (which ime is desirable).

It's strange that this isn't clearly mentioned in the documentation, that this is how you upgrade k8s in minikube; just stop and start an existing profile's cluster with a new version of k8s..